# Creating a file on the fly and return on the fly (Perl)

Tags: perl, file

I have to create a file based on user inputs on the server. Return that file.
Now, I don't want the files once the file is returned to the user (otherwise they will fill up my disk space).
Is there a good way of doing this?
I have to do it in Perl.

Thank You.

Comment: I have to create a zip file of a static file and some data and return the zip to the client. I am using Archive::Zip for it. I have not explored File::Temp yet, thank you for pointing it out.

Comment: TJ-, please [open a new question](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/ask) for your File::Temp problem and post your source code and Perl version.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

If you're building a zip file and immediately sending it back to the client then you have lots of options.

You could use [`writeToFileHandle`](http://search.cpan.org/dist/Archive-Zip/lib/Archive/Zip.pm#writeToFileHandle) combined with [`IO::Scalar`](http://search.cpan.org/perldoc?IO::Scalar) to write the zip file data straight to a string and send that back. This approach avoids the whole file issue completely.

You could also use `writeToFileHandle` combined with [`File::Temp`](http://search.cpan.org/dist/File-Temp/) to write to a temporary file and then stream that file back. The `UNLINK` option for `File::Temp` will help you automatically clean up the temp file as well.

Comment: Thanks for the tip. Any idea how can I resolve this -> [Can't resolve method "???" overloading """" in package "overload" at /<path>/File/Temp.pm line 1044.] when calling File::Temp->new()

Comment: Why not send it directly to the client with writeToFileHandle (using IO::Handle->fdopen if necessary)?

Comment: @Andy: As I said, "lots of options".

Comment: @TJ: It is producing that error just by calling `File::Temp->new()`?

Comment: Yes. That is the only place where I use File::Temp.

Comment: @TJ: And `make test` passed? Any idea what directory it is trying to use for temp files or if there is a permissions issue somewhere? Line 1044 is just the usual `bless` thing so the error makes no sense to me.

Comment: @mu. Thanks for the suggestions. I was able to get the thing working with writeToHandle and IO::Scalar. However, I am facing a problem. My zips are areound 4.5 Mbs in size. When I start downloading (on the client) side. The download fails after about half the download. Am I missing some HTTPResponse headers that I should include? (I tried using FF and Chrome and tried the client side troubleshooting, but that didn't help much). The message on FF is - "C:\x.zip could not be saved, because the source file could not be read.
Try again later, or contact the server administrator."

Comment: Are you having timeout issues? Text vs binary mode issues? Try saving the file on the server and see if you can unzip it there.

Answer (score 0):

This is what I created and works for me. When user opening some URL on my page I am creating ZIP archive on the fly and sending it to user.

If change "-" to "file.zip" it will save archive into your hosting/server (and don't need print "content type").

Tried with big size files (400-500Mb each file) - all ok.

```
   use IO::Compress::Zip qw(:all);

   my @files = ('example.gif', 'example1.png', 'example2.jpg', 'example3.avi', 'example4.mov');

   my $path = "/home/********/**********";

   print "Content-Type:application/zip\n";
   print "Content-Disposition: attachment; filename=\"filename.zip\"\n\n";

   my $z;

   foreach my $file (@files) {
      if ($z) {
         $z->newStream(Name => $file, Method => ZIP_CM_STORE);
      } else {
         $z = new IO::Compress::Zip "-", Name => $file, Method => ZIP_CM_STORE;
      }

      open(FILE, "<", "$path/$file");
      binmode FILE;

      my ($buf, $data, $n);

      while (($n = read FILE,$data, 1024) != 0) {
         $z->print($data);
      }

      close(FILE);
   }

   $z->close;

   exit;
```